# Display a json array of object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of object and want display in a single line in ReactJS. The object look like:

```
[
  {
     name:"jane",
     age : "20"
  },
  {
     name:"mary",
     age : "21"
  }
  {
     name:"john",
     age : "19"
  }
]
```

I want display the result to be :

```
jane 20, mary 21, john 19
```

e.g

```
<span className="name>data.name</span> <span className="age>data.age</span>
```

I have a function but that concat the value but not sure now to get my desire output

```
const getData = () => {
    var val = ''
    roles.map((data, inx) => {
      val = val + data.name + data.age

    })
    return (
      <span>{val}</span>
    )
  }
```

how can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenating like

```
val = val + data.name + data.age
```

won't work, because you want JSX elements (spans), not plain strings.

When mapping, check the index. If the index is 1 or more, add a comma before the first span when creating the JSX.

```js
const arr = [
  {
     name:"jane",
     age : "20"
  },
  {
     name:"mary",
     age : "21"
  },
  {
     name:"john",
     age : "19"
  }
]
const App = () => {
    return arr.map(({ name, age }, i) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            {i === 0 ? null : ','}
            <span className="name">{name}</span> <span className="age">{age}</span>
        </React.Fragment>
    ));
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```